# Typescript is getting mad when I try to create Mongodb documents with a "manual _id"

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I'm using Mongodb Driver for Node and I'm defining an _id property manually using Nanoid package (which creates an string id) to a specific collection.
Typescript is getting mad with me when I try to create a new document because Mongodb Driver defines that the _id property needs an ObjectId type, but it is getting a Nanoid string.
Anyone knows how to make typescript happy at this situation?

Comment: Which version of node-mongodb are you using?

Comment: @eol I'm using version 4.2.1